# Overlays and local ad insertion for live streaming

Tags: after-effects, streaming, live, broadcasting, obs

I have an event coming up and i am only broadcasting on youtube via OBS,i want to have overlays(the person who is on stage name appearing from the bottom) and locally stored sponsored ads to the stream, how do i do this?

i have searched most of the sites but i didn't find the answer i am searching for.I can have the overlays made and saved from After effects,but what is the best way to do this?

Comment: For reference, you are not doing "local" ad insertion in what you described. Local ad insertion is insertion at or near the viewer, typically by the network affiliate, the cable provider, or the CDN for OTT services. What you described is "network" ad insertion.

Comment: i have a set of advertisements from companies(10 seconds made ones) i need to add them to the stream when there is a break.I am the streamer

Comment: I think you need to search for automated play out systems.